# Salesforce Flow File Upload component get outputs before Next button

Tags: visual-workflow, fileupload

I have a flow on a community site (guest user context) using the standard file upload component to allow users to submit files.

Since guest users can't access `Opportunities` and I need to link these files to the opportunity, I'm using a Subflow in System Mode to make those file links in the element right after the File Upload screen.

- That subflow takes a collection variable (`v_ContentVersionIds`) which gets assigned in the Output Values of the file upload component.  That all works, except...
- If the user uploads a file (or group of files) the `v_ContentVersionIds` values are assigned.
- But, if the user uploads ***another*** file or group of files, the Ids of the second upload ***replace*** the first values and those initial files can't be linked to the Opportunity by the subflow.

Ideally, I need a way to add the `ContentVersionIds` of all the uploads, but without leaving the screen element (user is likely to drag and drop multiple times on the same screen).

If that won't work, I need a way to know (without leaving the screen) that files have been uploaded so that I can disable the upload and provide instructions for subsequent uploads.

It appears that `v_ContentVersionIds` does not get assigned UNTIL the next button is pressed, so I can't use that value for conditional visibility or disabling the component.

Any ideas?